# 2nd For loop doesn't work until the 2nd time I run my Sub

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have some VBA code that first checks if a column exist and if it is needed to insert some columns. Then it takes values from one cell and splits them into the new columns.

My problem is when I run the MACRO it only does the inserting of the columns and then I have to run the macro a second time to get the values inserted. I cannot find a similar post about this problem but I am guessing its has been asked before so if you have a link that would be great also.

Is there a reason why my 2nd for loop is not running after the first one finesses?

Is there a way to tell my code to continue after one For loop ends?

```
Dim starting_string As String
Dim primary_code As String
Dim primary_group As String
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim space_ndex As Integer
Dim working_string As String

Sub controller()
    Set rng1 = Range("G1:G1")
    Set rng2 = Range("G2:G1429")

    For Each cell In rng1
        If cell.Value <> "Code" Then
            Range("G:H").EntireColumn.Insert
            Cells(1, "G").NumberFormat = "@"
            Cells(1, "H").NumberFormat = "@"
            Cells(1, "G").Value = "Code"
            Cells(1, "H").Value = "Primary Group"
        End If
    Next cell

    For Each cellg In rng2
        working_string = cellg.Offset(0, -1).Value
        If Trim(working_string) <> "" Then
            space_ndex = InStr(cellg.Offset(, -1).Value, " ")
            cellg.Offset(0, 0).NumberFormat = "@"
            cellg.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
            cellg.Offset(0, 0).Value = Left(working_string, space_ndex)
            cellg.Offset(0, 1).Value = Mid(working_string, space_ndex, 100)
        End If
    Next cellg

End Sub
```

Comment: `For each cell in rng1`.  `rng1` is a single cell.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes. I was having problems using Cells so I tried it with range and it worked fine. I guess its overkill I can change it to cells. Still I do not think that is affecting the issue with 2 for loops.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're setting rng2 to "G" before inserting new columns in "G", hence your rng2 is then actually column "I".
On second pass it gets re-set to "G".

Edit: Try using break points and F8 to find out what your code is doing, it helps ;)

Comment: Wow. Simply moving `rng2` to just above the 2nd loop fixed the problem. Thanks. I would have never thought of this. I assumed it was only concerned with the actual lettering of the column and didn't realize the range broke after the insertion of columns. Can't accept the answer for another 9 min but I will once the time elapses.

Comment: In reply to your edit I have been using `Debug.Print()`. I am new to VBA so I was not aware of breakpoints. Thanks I will look into them as well.